# AngularJS - Page refresh doesn't route properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have an Angular app with the following routes and an Express API.

```
angular.module('angRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'public/views/home.html',
        controller: 'SignUpController'
    })
    .when('/signUp', {
        templateUrl: 'public/views/signUp.html',
        controller: 'SignUpController'
    })
    .when('/signedUp', {
        templateUrl: 'public/views/signedUp.html',
        controller: 'SignUpController'
    })
    .when('/board', {
        templateUrl: 'public/views/board.html',
        controller: 'BoardController',
        resolve: {
            userData: ['$http', function($http){
                return $http.get('/board')
                    .then(function(response){
                        return response.data;
                    });
            }]
        }
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

When I access my app at `localhost:3000`, it loads and I can navigate through my pages fine. However, when I refresh the page when I'm on `localhost:3000/signUp`, `localhost:3000/signedUp`, or `localhost:3000/board` the page won't render. When refreshing `localhost:3000`, the page loads fine.

When refreshing `localhost:3000/signUp`, or `localhost:3000/signedUp` I get the error page "Cannot GET /signUp" or "Cannot GET /signedUp". When I refresh the `localhost:3000/board` page I get the JSON that my Express API sends back for that route, but it's just shown in raw format as my HTML is not rendering.

In the Chrome Devtools Network tab I can see that the refresh sends a `signUp` request instead of the `signUp.html - public/views` request I see when I navigate to the page.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using html5Mode. It removes '#' from your url, that's common issue - after reloading page it won't render, because you have basically single page application, and routes after '#' are virtual. Without this sign, you will see only root(home) page. To fix that, you need to change settings on serverside. It depends which server you going to use, apache, nodejs, nginx, etc
So the simplest solution, remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and use '#' in your route

Comment: Great thanks so much!